# As good as it gets. What's the meaning of this sentence?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> As good as it gets.

What's the meaning of this sentence?

Does the sentence mean "It is good only to the degree that it gets." or " It is good without limit(i.e. The more it gets the better it is)."

Comment: [**be as good as it gets**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/be-as-good-as-it-gets). That's  often used as the "disappointed" version of ***It doesn't get any better than this*** (this is really good). When someone tells you this is as good as it gets, the meaning is still just literal - it doesn't get any better - but it carries the implication ***...so don't bother hoping for anything better*** (even though the situation isn't very good).

Comment: @FumbleFingers As always, you are excellent and stay in detail.

Comment: In "as good as it gets", is there something omitted after the verb 'gets'?

Comment: No. Compare *As hard as he tried, it wasn't enough.* There's nothing "missing" after ***tried*** there. For reasons I can't explain, it's not really idiomatic to put the optional adverbial / contrastive clause ***after*** the main assertion in my example. If the positions of those two parts of the sentence are reversed, we have to switch to something like *It wasn't enough, **even though he tried [very] hard / for all his trying***.

Comment: In "as good as it gets", the verb 'gets' means 'becomes'?

Comment: Yes. You could paraphrase *This is as good as it gets* as *It will not **become** any better than this*. But although that *means* the same, it's not very idiomatic. As pointed out, the version in the question title is normally used to imply speaker *doesn't* think it's very good (ruefully admitting it's *the best of a bad bunch*). In principle *It doesn't get any better than this* carries exactly the same meaning, but in practice that's the version used when speaker *does* think it's very good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means "nothing better is available".  The sense can range from positive to weakly negative:

> It's not a great bike, but for £700, it's as good as it gets.

This means that the bike is good value, but not as good as a more expensive bike.

> This restaurant is as good as it gets in our town.

Perhaps other cities have better restaurants, but this one is pretty good, it is the best one locally.

Comment: I don't agree with ***but this one is pretty good*** in final paragraph. The implication is usually ***it's not very good, but it's the best available option.***

Comment: That may be the implication,  but you would need more context.  If you know that the town has many good restaurants, then "as good as it gets in our town" may mean "extremely good"

Comment: I said "usually". Unless context makes it obvious the "it's really good" sense applies, I would always assume the "poor as it may be, it's all there is" sense for ***This is as good as it gets***. That's why we have the alternative phrasing ***It doesn't get any better than this***.

Answer (score 2):

"This is the most good it's going to be"

As good as it gets ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as%20good%20as%20it%20gets))

1 —used to say that nothing better is possible or available It's not a great restaurant, but in this part of the city, it's as good as it gets.
2 —used to say that something is very good and cannot be improved